# Adding convenience initializers in extensions and invoking them on subclasses

Tags: cocoa-touch, inheritance, swift

I’m trying to add an extension method to `UIView` in Swift like so:

```
extension UIView {
    convenience init(superview: UIView) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect())
        superview.addSubview(self)
    }
}
```

Later, I can use this new initializer, but **only on UIView** and I can’t figure out how to use this on my own subclasses.

```
var poView : UIView = UIView(superview: someSuperview) // Just dandy
var myViewSubclass : MyViewSubclass(superview: someSuperview) // No good.
```

Now, my view subclass implements both `init(frame: CGRect)` and `init(coder: NSCoder)` and currently, nothing else.

Why can’t I use my convenience initializer?

Answer (score 2):

In order to inherit added convenience initialiser automatically, your  `MyViewSubclass` must also override plain `init()`, which is inherited from `NSObject`.

```
class MyViewSubclass {
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: It seems like `init()`, `init(frame)`, and `init(coder)` are all designated initializers of `UIView`. This is not obvious from the "header" that's exposed to us though.

Comment: `init()` is inherited from `NSObject` and `init(coder:)` is declared   in `NSCoding` protocol. That's why those two cannot be found in the `UIView` class definition.